# Integer division in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, division

How can I divide two numbers in Python 2.7 and get the result with decimals?

I don't get it why there is difference:

in Python 3:

```
>>> 20/15
1.3333333333333333
```

in Python 2:

```
>>> 20/15
1
```

Isn't this a modulo actually?

Comment: It's integer division, yo! `20 mod 15 == 5`

Comment: Try `float(20)/float(15)`

Comment: or float 20./15.

Comment: Related: *[Why does integer division yield a float instead of another integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/)*

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

In Python 2.7, the `/` operator is integer division if inputs are integers.

If you want float division (which is something I always prefer), just use this special import:

```
from __future__ import division
```

See it here:

```
>>> 7 / 2
3
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 7 / 2
3.5
>>>
```

Integer division is achieved by using `//`, and modulo by using `%`:

```
>>> 7 % 2
1
>>> 7 // 2
3
>>>
```

As commented by `user2357112`, this import has to be done before any other normal import.

Comment: It's worth noting that future statements have to appear before any other code in a module, particularly before non-future imports. Also, `import __future__` doesn't work.

Comment: Nice. Using `__future__` is almost always the recommended way

Comment: Thanks! I too always prefer that float division :)

Comment: Why is this preferable to `float(3)/float(2)`?

Comment: @dumbledad, it is more readable, concise and intuitive

Comment: Interesting - I do not find it more intuitive. If I know that `/` is integer division and the result has decimals I would be taken by suprise, and the `from __future__ import division` may be more than a screenful away.

Comment: Well, it is somehow subjective, but for me, coming from other languages,  it was confusing that dividing 3/2==1. Many people may agree, because float division is the default in python 3

Comment: // is not integer division, it is floor division.
3 // 2 = 1, -3 // 2 = -2.

Answer (score 61):

In Python 3, `/` is float division

In Python 2, `/` is integer division (assuming `int` inputs)

In both 2 *and* 3, `//` is integer division

(To get float division in Python 2 requires either of the operands be a float, either as `20.` or `float(20)`)

Comment: Thanks for the paranthetical -- it was what I was curious about.

Answer (score 17):

In Python 2.x, make sure to have at least one operand of your division in `float`. Multiple ways you may achieve this as the following examples:

```
20. / 15
20 / float(15)
```

Answer (score 12):

"/" is integer division in Python 2, so it is going to round to a whole number. If you would like a decimal returned, just change the type of one of the inputs to float:

`float(20)/15 #1.33333333`