# my program is not allowing me to call a variable from a previous function in python

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error

1. My questions are found in the comments below

   ```
   def Distanceinput():
       distance = eval(input('Enter a distance (in light years):'))
       print("Velocity Relative time to reach", distance, "light years")
   ```

   the problem is coming in the following chunk of code where I attempt to use distance from above but it comes back as an error.  what can I do to  rectify this problem?

   ```
   def velocity(velocityPercent):
       DilationFactor = (((1 - (velocityPercent ** 2)) / 10000) ** 0.5)
       perceptualSpeed = (distance * DilationFactor) * 100
       print(velocityPercent, + "% of light", perceptualSpeed, "years.")
   ```

   the above chunk of code is what is causing problems

   ```
   def Time():
       Distanceinput()
       print()
       velocity(10)
       print()
       velocity(25)
       print()
       velocity(50)
       print()
       velocity(75)
       print()
       velocity(90)
       print()
       velocity(99)
       print()
   Time()
   ```

Comment: Variables declared inside a function are local to that function.

Comment: means you have to pass `distance` value to `velocity` function?

Comment: Protip: Start using function **arguments** and **return values**

Comment: `distance` is local to `Distanceinput` so therefore not visible for `velocity` [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: yes I need to be able to call the distance number that was input by the user in the first function in the second function which is called the velocity function.

Comment: please sort the formatting

Comment: I just did, I hope that is better

Comment: Exception `negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power` is coming for `DilationFactor = (((1 - (velocityPercent ** 2)) / 10000) ** 0.5)` statement.

Comment: there isn't a problem with the math the problem is coming late.  Also the velocityPercent is a decimal so the number isn't negative and the problem  works.

Comment: The problem is coming with referencing distance in the velocity function.

Answer (score 3):

```
distance = None
def Distanceinput():
    global distance
    distance = eval(input('Enter a distance (in light years):'))
    print("Velocity Relative time to reach", distance, "light years")
```

Comment: You should also likely explain why the `global` keyword is used. :)

Comment: for whatever reason every time I try a global variable it doesn't work.  I just tried again and nothing changed in the error output.

Comment: I pasted your Code and it works. There is just another error in the syntax of `print(velocityPercent, + "% of light", perceptualSpeed, "years.")` the `+` should be deleted. (You trying to add a string and a integer)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `local` and `global` variables are that local variables may only be accessed inside a function, whereas a global variable may be accessed anywhere throughout the program. Note the names, local (available within a certain area), and global, available everywhere.

```
def Distanceinput():
    distance = eval(input('Enter a distance (in light years):'))
    print("Velocity Relative time to reach", distance, "light years")

def velocity(velocityPercent):
    DilationFactor = (((1 - (velocityPercent ** 2)) / 10000) ** 0.5)
    perceptualSpeed = (distance * DilationFactor) * 100
    print(velocityPercent, + "% of light", perceptualSpeed, "years.")
```

Your `Distanceinput()` is fine. You should return the value though so that it can be used later on in the program. Returning to the local and global variables, `distance` in `velocity(velocityPercent)` is considered a local variable. You haven't said anywhere in your function that you needed to access the variable `distance` that has a value elsewhere in your program. You can accomplish this like so:

```
# Somewhere at the top of your code...
distance = None
```

Then, in your function:

```
def Distanceinput():
    global distance # Says that your function requires the following global variable
    # rest of your code
    return distance # In case you need the output of the function later on.

def velocity(velocityPercent):
    global distance # Again, the same action as above

    DilationFactor = (((1 - (velocityPercent ** 2)) / 10000) ** 0.5)
    perceptualSpeed = (distance * DilationFactor) * 100
    print(velocityPercent, " % of light ", perceptualSpeed, " years.")
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I organized your code a bit differently. 
Also, if i understood correctly there were some bugs in your velocity function, so i changed it as well.

---

Explanation:

- `eval` and `exec` can execute malicious code, so unless you are the only person using your program, try to avoid them. `int` will work just fine for given problem.
- I created a class, from which you can create different instances. Each time you create an instance you get to input the `distance`.
- `\n` is the newline character.
- `velocityPercent /= 100.` is equivalent to *set velocityPercent to
  its previous value divided by 100*. Note that its `100.` with a dot,
  in case you are using [python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3). Then i removed the `/100000`
  in `DilationFactor`, and `100` in `perceptualSpeed`.

One thing you could change is the output of `velocity`.

```
class Galaxy(object):

    DISTANCE = 'i like dogs'

    def Distanceinput(self):
        self.DISTANCE = int(input('\nEnter a distance (in light years):'))
        print("Velocity Relative time to reach", self.DISTANCE, "light years")

    def velocity(self, velocityPercent):
        velocityPercent /= 100.
        DilationFactor = ((1 - (velocityPercent ** 2)) ** 0.5)
        perceptualSpeed = self.DISTANCE * DilationFactor
        print(velocityPercent,  "% of light", perceptualSpeed, "years.")

    def Time(self):
        self.Distanceinput()
        print()
        for vel in (10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 99):
            self.velocity(vel)


galaxy_1 = Galaxy()

galaxy_1.Time()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 way of doing this :

- You work with a global variable
- You pass the variable in parameter

Look here : http://paste2.org/_wpZH5I8m

Comment: how is that going to help me in the variable function with the syntax error that keeps coming up regarding python not understanding what distance is?