# Python Tip Calculator Bug

Tags: python

The following code should run smoothly, but for some reason Terminal tells me that there is a problem with it. My question is at the bottom.

```
print 'Welcome to Cash Calculator!'

cash = input('How much was the original price of the services or goods you paid for, excluding vat?')
tip = input('How much more, as a percentage, would you like to give as a tip?')

tip = tip/100

print tip

vat = 1.2

cash_vat = cash * vat

can = (cash_vat + ((tip/100) * cash_vat))

can = cash_vat + tip * cash_vat

print """
Thank you for your co-operation.
The price excluding the tip is %r,
and the total price is %d.
"""  % (cash_vat, can)
```

When the code above runs Terminal gives out:

```
Welcome to Cash Calculator!
How much was the original price of the services or goods you paid for, excluding vat?100
How much more, as a percentage, would you like to give as a tip?10
0

Thank you for your co-operation.
The price excluding the tip is 120.0,
and the total price is 120.
```

What seems to be the problem? It keeps thinking that the tip is 0.  I am a complete beginner.

Comment: @MorganThrapp it's not about reading integers, it's about integer division.

Comment: @bereal `input()` return a `str()`. The OP is doing `"100"/100` hence the error.

Comment: @Leb it's Python2, `input()` evals the string. Otherwise it would be `TypeError`.

Comment: @bereal you're right, `raw_input()` will fix then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3) the division operator `/` performes integer division if both the numerator and denominator are `ints` (which in this case they are, since you used `input()`). So the operation:

```
# if tip = 10
tip = 10/100
```

Will return `0`, because both values are of type `int`.

---

Since you need float division, you can either import the  `division` operator from the [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) module:

```
from __future__ import division

tip = 10 / 100 # returns 0.1
```

Or, alternatively, cast the `tip` of type `int` to a `float` before actually dividing:

```
tip = float(10) / 100 # returns 0.1
```

Comment: @RichardDickins: if this answered your question, would you accept it? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer - this is how we mark questions as solved and answers as correct. It is also a good way of recognising the effort of the poster, as it gives them a few extra reputation points.