# Python - Division and floating point numbers

Tags: python

According to the Python tutorial here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

this gives a floating point number:

```
>>> 17 / 3  # classic division returns a float
5.666666666666667
```

However, when I try it I get:

```
>>> 17 / 3
5
```

How come? FWIW, I'm using `Python 2.7.10` on the Mac.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python

Comment: A better dupe [Division in Python 2.7. and 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21316968)

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour changed between Python 2.7 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the URL:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html
https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html
```

The URL you posted is for Python 3, but you are using Python 2.7.

There's a dropdown at the top of the page. You can select `2.7` from there to get the documentation for Python 2.7:

> ```
> >>> 17 / 3  # int / int -> int
> 5
> ```