# CodeWars "Find The Parity Outlier" error?

Tags: python

I'm completing [this Codewars exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5526fc09a1bbd946250002dc/train/python). Here are the instructions:

> You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but
>   could be very large) containing integers. The integers in the array
>   are either entirely odd or entirely even except for a single integer
>   N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns N.
>
> For example:
>
> [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
>
> Should return: 11
>
> [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
>
> Should return: 160

However, when I submit the following code:

```
def ifeven(list):
     #Determine if we are dealing with list of evens or odds
    sum = 0
    for ran in (0,1,2):
        sum += abs(list[ran])%2
    avg = sum/3
    r_avg = round(avg)
    return r_avg == 0

def find_outlier(integers):
    even =  ifeven(integers)
    new = []
    for num in integers:
        new.append(num%2)
    if even:
        loc = new.index(1)
    else:
        loc = new.index(0)
    return integers[loc]
```

With this test case (see exercise link):

```
test.assert_equals(find_outlier([1,2,3]), 2)
```

For some I reason I get the error `1 should equal 2` even though if I run the code on another compiler, I get `2` as the (correct) answer.

Is the issue with my code or Codewars's compiler?

Comment: Check the version of python being used. Python 2 and 3 handle the `/` operator differently. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3

Comment: ^That was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please post this as an answer or tag as a duplicate.

Comment: Just FYI, your code is doing a lot more work than you really have to. [Here's a shorter solution](http://pastebin.com/g0p6hkiG). We can chat about it on here if you have questions. Happy coding!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes -- I like that solution, somewhat reflects my similar approach of looking at the first three elements but in a much more concise manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by /u/Prune, here is the answer:

Check the version of python being used. Python 2 and 3 handle the / operator differently. See here: [Division in Python 2.7. and 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3)