# Programming Decision Structures

Tags: python

A wholesale egg company bases their prices on the number of eggs purchased:

0 up to but not including 4 dozen $0.50 per dozen 4 up to but not including 6 dozen $0.45 per dozen 6 up to but not including 11 dozen $0.40 per dozen 11 or more dozen $0.35 per dozen Extra Eggs are priced at 1/12 the per dozen price

Create a program that prompts the user for the number of eggs, and then calculates bill.  The application output should look similar to: Enter the number of eggs purchased: 18 The bill is equal to: $0.75

**This is the question and here is my code:**

```
eggs = int(raw_input("Please enter the amount of eggs you have."))

if (eggs >=12 and eggs <=47):
    dozen = int(eggs) // 12
    dozenprice = float(dozen) * 0.50
    extra = float(eggs) % 12
    extraprice = float(extra)*((1/12)*0.50)
    total = float(dozenprice) + float(extraprice)
    print "Your total is " + str(total)

if (eggs >=48 and eggs<=71):
    dozen = int(eggs) // 12
    dozenprice = float(dozen) * 0.45
    extra = float(eggs) % 12
    extraprice = float(extra)*((1/12)*0.45)
    total = float(dozenprice) + int(extraprice)
    print "Your total is " + str(total)

if (eggs >=72 and eggs <=131):
    dozen = int(eggs) // 12
    dozenprice = float(dozen) * 0.40
    extra = float(eggs) % 12
    extraprice = float(extra)*((1/12)*0.40)
    total = float(dozenprice) + int(extraprice)
    print "Your total is " + str(total)

if (eggs >=132):
    dozen = int(eggs) // 12
    dozenprice = float(dozen) * 0.35
    extra = float(eggs) % 12
    extraprice = float(extra)*((1/12)*0.35)
    total = float(dozenprice) + int(extraprice)
    print "Your total is " + str(total)
```

**Why isn't the price for the extra eggs appearing?**

Comment: White space matters in Python, that's not syntactically valid.

Comment: @CliffBurton the pasted in code was formatted improperly. There is a legitimate misunderstanding of how Python2.7 interprets `/` normal division, although from the question not clear that's the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1/12` in python2.7 is `0`, because they are integers and using integer division you get 0. Then you get `0 * price`...

`1/12.` will produce `0.083`, as the `12.` forces it to be a float.
Alternatively, you can get Python3 behavior [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317109/3579910):

```
from __future__ import division
```

Without that, in Python2.7, [`/ & // are equivalent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-2-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division).

Comment: To add onto this, you can get the behavior you expect by starting your program with `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: alternatively cast both numbers as a float. `float(1)/float(12)`

Comment: @user3030010 I've added that to the description.

Comment: @user3030010 i'm sorry, i'm immensely new to python programming so i'm a bit confused. how would I start my program with from_future_ import division? thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: Just stick that line verbatim at the top of your program, like any other import statement. It takes the new division behavior (from Python 3) and lets you use it in Python 2. So if you were using Python 3, you wouldn't even have to do that.

Comment: @user3030010 Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, it is a problem in your python code. I modified the first part as follows

```
if (12 <= eggs <= 47):
   dozen = eggs/ 12
   dozenprice = dozen * 0.50
   extra = eggs % 12.0
   extraprice = extra*((1.0/12.0)*0.50)
   total = dozenprice + extraprice
   print "Your total is " + str(total)
```

Result is :

```
Please enter the amount of eggs you have : 18

Your total is 0.75
```

You No need to use `extra = float(eggs) % 12` because egg value is an integer. Simplified the if() variables as `if (12 <= eggs <= 47):`