# Python Sort List of Lists

Tags: python, list

I want to sort this list from lowest to highest value of  `whole[i][0] / whole[i][1]`

```
before -> whole = [[60, 20], [100, 50], [120, 30]]

after  -> whole = [[100,50],[60,20],[120,30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `list.sort()` along with *lambda expression* as:

```
>>> whole = [[60, 20], [100, 50], [120, 30]]

>>> whole.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]/float(x[1]))
#  get the resultant from div as a `float` ^  in Python 2
#  However you may skip the `float` type-cast in Python 3
```

Final value hold by `whole` list after doing `.sort()` will be:

```
>>> whole
[[100, 50], [60, 20], [120, 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorted with a lambda:

```
sorted_list = sorted(whole, lambda x: x[0]/float(x[1]))
```

Comment: `list.sort` works in-place, your `sorted_list` will be `None`. Better to use `sorted` if you want to create a new sorted list.

Comment: Why did you apply the float to x[1] and not x[0]?

Comment: In python 2.x if you divide two ints you will always get an int back regardless of whether or not there is a remainder. If at least one of them is a float you get a float back. Here is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21317017/6237583) that addresses this.

Comment: default division in python 2.x is integer so 4/5 will result in 0. so he converted the denominator to float another option is to import division library from fututre i.e.  `from __future__ import
      division` . if you are using python 3 it is not a problem as default division is float.https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/