# python floating point calculations

Tags: python, math

How should I expect Python to handle a simple floating point calculation like this:

```
float(6/4)
```

The output from this in the shell is

```
1.0
```

I would expect this to be 1.5, so what gives?

Comment: Or:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21316968/748858

Comment: you are casting the RESULT of 6/4 into float, the result of int division is an int, instead do `float(6)/4` or `6.0/4`

Comment: `from __future__ import division`
    
    `a = float(5/4)`
    
    `print(a)`

`output: 1.25`

Comment: Thanks, I have a handle on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is using integer division here.

Comment: I see. Silly me, I should use 6.0/4.0 instead. Or, I could get cute and do something like (6 +0.0)/4. Thanks

Comment: @user675712 -- or, more future-proof, you should use `from __future__ import division`