# Getting Different result from same Return type in swift and python

Tags: python, swift, python-3.x, swift3

I am quite new in Python.

> When I have created a simple object in swift:-

```
let one = 7.0
let two = 2.0
var three = one / two
print(three)
let first = 7
let second = 2
let third = CGFloat(first/second)
print(third)
```

## Output Result is:- 3.5 and 3.0

> I am creating simple objects in python. Using Python in the terminal.

```
>>> 7/2.
3.5
>>> float(7/2)
3.0)
```

## Output Result is:- 3.5 and 3.0

Why the 7/2. auto read the integer to float. When I am declaring the two different Integer as like that:-

```
>>> a = 7 
>>> b = 2
>>> c = a / b.
```

It shows error. invalid syntax.

How in Python generate an auto result on 7/2. and getting a result.

When using in objects it shows error.

Comment: `c = a / b.` is a syntax error, it expects an attribute. try `decimal.Decimal(a/b)` (in python3, no need to specify this, the decimal is automatic)

Comment: @PRMoureu I am new Python when I try decimal.Decimal(a/b) its give me error name 'decimal' is not defined

Comment: `import decimal` is needed first

Comment: Looks like you are using Python 2.x in contrast to the tag. The / operator there produces an integer, when given integer inputs. So 7/2 is 3, even if you cast it to float afterwards. On the other hand 7/2. is short for 7/2.0, which results in a float, since the second argument is a float. Using the decimal point after a variable name makes no sense, that is the invalid syntax error.

Comment: You can make sure to receive a float from c=a/b by casting one of the arguments to float explicitly *before* dividing: c=float(a)/b

Comment: @ChristianKönig Whan, I am using 7/2. its auto casting. but when we use that in the object (c = a / b .) it shows error. As you provide ( c = float(a)/b ) show the result correctly. What the reason behind that. Is every time we use integer object we need to casting one of the arguments explicitly before any math calculation.

Comment: With 2. you are entering a literal number in float format. Using a variable name you cannot use the decimal point to auto-cast. Think of a = "1", you are using the " to denote a string, but a=1; b="a" won't cast the contents of a to string. The behaviour of / changed in Python 3, such that a float is automatically returned for 7/2.

Comment: Have a look here for further information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3

Comment: @ChristianKönig I am just asking how that handle auto in 7/2. And your suggested duplicate question give the differences the division of different Python. I am asking the reason. not the Difference between two versions

Comment: The reason in Python2 is, that / returns the same type as its input. If you only provide integer arguments, an integer will be returned.

Comment: @PRMoureu Why do you even add `decimal` to this mix? `float` is a more basic type and what most people will encounter. It also happens to give an exact result for `3.5`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = 7 
>>> b = 2
```

if your want  got `3.5`, used

```
>>> c = a / float(b)
```

if your want  got `3`, used

```
>>> c = a / b
```