# How to replace values in pandas data frame according to a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I    have a pandas data frame it looks like this

```
 0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262
        0       30  84  126 135 137 179 242 342 426 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        1       24  53  75  134 158 192 194 211 213 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2       51  143 173 257 446 491 504 510 559 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        3       1   20  22  92  124 149 211 335 387 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        4       34  51  56  106 110 121 163 233 266 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to divide each number in the data frame by 7 and put the result in the data frame instead of the number, I was testing with a for loop, but it
doesn't work for me

```
for i in x:
    y = i % 7
    if y == 0:
        x.replace(i, 7)
```

It should work but when I print the data frame I can't see the change, I even tried to replace a specific value, but also no change.

How should I do it and I was wondering what is the best solution memory wise since I'm trying to scale this to a bigger data frame

lets say we have a line like this

```
 0 8 30 28 36 40 45 0 56
```

the output I want should be,

```
 0 1 2 7 1 5 3 0 7
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with chained condition for check `0`:

```
print (df)
   0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  253  254  255  256  257
0  0   8   30   28   36   40   45    0   56  426    0    0    0    0    0
1  1  24   53   75  134  158  192  194  211  213    0    0    0    0    0
2  2  51  143  173  257  446  491  504  510  559    0    0    0    0    0
3  3   1   20   22   92  124  149  211  335  387    0    0    0    0    0
4  4  34   51   56  106  110  121  163  233  266    0    0    0    0    0

mdf = df % 7
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where((mdf == 0) & (df != 0), 7, mdf),
                  columns=df.columns, 
                  index=df.index)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  253  254  255  256  257
0  0  1  2  7  1  5  3  0  7  6    0    0    0    0    0
1  1  3  4  5  1  4  3  5  1  3    0    0    0    0    0
2  2  2  3  5  5  5  1  7  6  6    0    0    0    0    0
3  3  1  6  1  1  5  2  1  6  2    0    0    0    0    0
4  4  6  2  7  1  5  2  2  2  7    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Ok it's nearly what I'm looking for, but i want to except all the zeros from that meaning to leave the zeros alone work on other values or if I could replace the zeros from the mask with another value say 7, because they represent different labels

Comment: and what does the the 7 parameter stand for

Comment: So you want dont replace columns with `0` only?

Comment: No I want to replace the resulting zeros from this mask with another value to distinguish between it and the zeros that existed before because this data represents days of different weeks and the zero means no days, but in that mask the zero will represent sundays and the days that he didn't show up

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Comment: unfortunately no, I will try to explain more
This is the description of my data

 0: no visit on the next week
 1: Monday
 2: Tuesday
 3: Wednesday
 4: Thursday
 5: Friday
 6: Saturday
 7: Sunday

if I get Sunday the output of i % 7 will be zero, also if i = 0 the output will be zero so I want Sundays to have different values meaning I want to replace the zeros from the mask with another value. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. Why is not possible add desired output from your sample data? Maybe it help.

Comment: Or do you want set each 7th column to `7` ?

Comment: lets say we have a line like this 

0 8 30 28 36 40 45 0 56
the output I want should be,

0 1 2 7 1 5 3 0 7

Comment: And logic? why `5` ? why `3` ?

Comment: it's the same x % 7 except for values 56 or 28 when the output is zero I want it to be 7

Comment: and zero values should remain zeros

Comment: I get it, please give me a sec

Comment: I edit answer, also first row was created by your new data, please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is exactly what I'm looking for. I want to try something different with the same data and I was wondering if you could take a look at that question and help if you could 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822149/how-can-i-sessionize-rows-in-pandas-based-on-week-days

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame method [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) will apply a function to each cell. The first parameter of the function will be the cell's contents.

```
import pandas as pd

# Just an example df
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Column1":[7*x for x in range(1,11)], "Column2":[7*x for x in range(11,21)]})

print(df)

   Column1  Column2
0        7       77
1       14       84
2       21       91
3       28       98
4       35      105
5       42      112
6       49      119
7       56      126
8       63      133
9       70      140
```

Below is a simple function and applying it.

Note that you'll need to store the results in a new variable (it'll display the results but it doesn't change the original DataFrame).

The function assumes Python 3.
If using Python 2 [division works differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3).

```
def divide_by_7(x):

    return x / 7

df2 = df.apply(divide_by_7)

print(df2)

   Column1  Column2
0      1.0     11.0
1      2.0     12.0
2      3.0     13.0
3      4.0     14.0
4      5.0     15.0
5      6.0     16.0
6      7.0     17.0
7      8.0     18.0
8      9.0     19.0
9     10.0     20.0
```

Using a function with a parameter of more than just the cell contents requires using the "args" parameter in the `apply()` method.

```
# A more flexible division function
def divide_by_n(x, n):

    return x / n

#If passing in arguments, pass them as a tuple to args parameter
df3 = df.apply(divide_by_n, args=(7,))

print(df3)

   Column1  Column2
0      1.0     11.0
1      2.0     12.0
2      3.0     13.0
3      4.0     14.0
4      5.0     15.0
5      6.0     16.0
6      7.0     17.0
7      8.0     18.0
8      9.0     19.0
9     10.0     20.0
```

There are other details of using `apply()`, for example to apply to create a new column. There are [examples in the pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#row-or-column-wise-function-application).

Comment: Ok it's nearly the answer I'm looking for. could you help me with this question using pandas also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841519/how-to-sessionize-data-in-pandas-rows