# How can I Sessionize rows in pandas based on week days?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame it looks like this

```
 0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262
0       30  84  126 135 137 179 242 342 426 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1       24  53  75  134 158 192 194 211 213 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
2       51  143 173 257 446 491 504 510 559 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
3       1   20  22  92  124 149 211 335 387 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

I want to sessionize each row based on week days 
I tried a for loop but I'm getting problems in time and memory

so basically what I want is to loop over each row with a step of size seven like this

```
range(1,1001,7)
```

check if the number is in my current range

if it's not put zero,

if it's in my range return my number % 7 +1,

then concatenate the numbers which fall in the same range into one list

so I should end up with 143 columns.

for the first row it should be like this

```
0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 [3,5] 0 0 0 0 and so on
```

Comment: What do you mean "if number is in my range" what is your range.

Comment: my range = range(1,1001,7)
sorry about that I added it to the code 
from 1 to 7 then from 8 to 14 then from 15 to 21 till 1001

Comment: so how could the first row, fourth column be 3? that values is 126

Comment: Then 126%7 + 1 != 3

Comment: no that 3 is for 30,  30 % 7 +1 

it should check in range from 1 to 7 first, it won't find the 30 put zero, look in the next range and so on until it reaches the range it is in after that continue till it finds the range of the next number

Answer (score 0):

**IIUC:**

You could just setup your dataframe to be filtered

If you had a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,(10,10)))

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   2  11  28  20  22   9  20  15   1  28
1   2   8  10   9  16   3   7   1  13  28
2   6   9  14  20  23   3   6   5  29   6
3  21  25  11  10  20  15  10  11  21   9
4   5  14  11  19   5   1  23   0   1   3
5  13  18  21   4  26   5  18   6  29  20
6   6   6  22   7  29  18  12  17   4   2
7   0  26  26   3  22  21  11  15  29  21
8   9  28  29   0  24  24  13   4   9  20
9   5  18   7  13  17   0  22  19  12  19


df['bottom'] = np.arange(0,len(df)) // 7 #set groups

df.iloc[:,:-1] = df.iloc[:,:-1]%7+1 #set values
df[(df <= df['bottom']+1) | (df >= df['bottom']+7)].fillna(0).astype(int) #filter
```

gives

```
   bottom  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  2  2  1
1       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  0  1
2       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0
3       0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
4       0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  0
5       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0
6       0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
7       0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  2  2  1
8       0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
9       0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I don't get setting groups line and the filtering, could you illustrate more since I'm not getting my desired output and thanks a lot it seems very interesting and close

Comment: is there something like pd.cut that I could use on the rows

Comment: you should print one line at a time. `bottom` is a linear index that we use a floor divisor to make groups of seven 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0. Now just preform your operations on the dataframe. Last where the dataframe is within the range, you keep the value and set all the others to zero