# How to sessionize data in pandas rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, it looks like this

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ... 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262
0   30  84  126 135 137 179 242 342 426 456 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1   24  53  75  134 158 192 194 211 213 238 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
2   51  143 173 257 446 491 504 510 559 616 ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

so basically what I want is to loop over each row with a step of size seven like this

```
my_range = range(1,1002,7)
```

check if the number is in my current range

if it's not put zero,

if it's in my range return my number % 7 +1,

then concatenate the numbers which fall in the same range into one list

so I should end up with 143 columns.

for the first row it should be like this

```
0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 [3,5] 0 0 0 0 and so on
```

I wrote this code and tested it on that a list to show what I want to do

```
z = [30,84,126,135,136,137,179,242,342,426]
c = []
def counter(maximum, inc):  # resetable generator from doc example
    i = 1
    while i < maximum:
        val = (yield i)
        # If value provided, change counter
        if val is not None:
            i = val
        else:
            i += inc


ig = counter(1002, 7)

for m in z:
    for i in ig:
        # catch multiple nums in same range
        if m < i:
            clast = c.pop()
            # inline if-else inside append converts int to tuple to add m to
            c.append((clast if type(clast) == tuple else (clast,)) + (m%7+1,))
            # reset ig count
            ig.send(i - 7)
            break

        if i <= m < i+7:
            c.append(m%7+1)
            break
        else:
            c.append(0)
# exhaust ig if you really want full count = 143
for i in ig:
    c.append(0)

print(len(c))
```

the code above outputs

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, (3, 4, 5), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and this is how each row should look like

and   `len(c) = 143`

Is there an easy way to implement that code over pandas rows or a better way to do it  on the data frame ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't your desired output start `[0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 3,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 1,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 1,
 0,
 [3, 4, 5], ...`?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: no you are right I just copied the wrong list, I will fix it. Thanks