# Long integer - python 3 vs python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need help to understand why this piece of code works correctly in python 2 but it doesn't work for python 3.

```
res = 76460188758730153884232119087179527041998988911761118644170793575
while res > 31:
    print(res%31)
    res = (res - res%31)/ 31
```

In python 2 the result of res%31 is: 23, 17, 2, 28, 17, 17

In python 3 the result of res%31 is: 23, 4.0, 17.0, 6.0, 21.0, 22.0, 18.0, 14.0

I'm having problems with long numbers in python3, but I can't solve them.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In Python 3, division always returns a float. If you want int division, like in Python 2, use ``//`` instead of ``/``

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `//` in Python 3.x to get integer as a result for the division. Using `/` in python3 always return a floating value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of big or small numbers but how python handles division as noted by @khelwood in his/her comment. In python3 `/` will return flaoat (or duoble to be more precise) and if you want to get integer (or long) you need to use `//`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3) or [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189).