# PySpark results different in Ubuntu vs Mac

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am using DataFrame in pyspark.sql. Why is the output different in Ubuntu vs Mac?

I am using only 10 documents, so N=10. The formula I used is `tf-idf = (1+log(tf))*log(N/df)`. So you can see actually Mac gives the correct output but Ubuntu (inside a VM) gives the wrong output.

My tf-idf column is a FloatType(). I calculated it using a udf function.

Ubuntu output:

[image: Ubuntu output]

Mac output:

[image: Mac output]

Comment: Maybe one uses Python 2 where `/` performs integer division?

Comment: Oh there is a difference btn Python 2 and Python 3 in the division? @timgeb can u explain more? Yes my Ubuntu is installed with Python 2.7.12 (provided by my lecturer). My Mac is installed with Python 3.6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned in comments that you are using python 2.7 in Ubuntu and Python 3.6 in Mac. Your pyspark code is doing divison (`/`)

In python3

```
>>> 3/2
1.5
```

In python2

```
>>> 3/2
1
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317109/2499625) for details on python2 vs python3 division and how to possibly adjust the behavior of your interpreter.