# Same code in Python 3.x and Python 2.x gives different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, division, median

I've built a function to calculate median (as the name indicates).

The function receives a list of ints, for instances [4,5,5,4] and should output 4,5.

The code:

```
def median(lst):
    lst.sort()
    a=int(len(lst)/2)
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        med=float((lst[a]+lst[a-1])/2)
    else:
        med=lst[a]
    return med
print(median([4,5,5,4]))
```

This works fine when using Python 3.x but not in Python 2.x. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assuming the division operator is the same in both Python 2 and 3. Instead (adapted from [mhlester](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317017/5675325)):

- in Python 2, / is integer division (*int* inputs);
- in Python 3, / is float division;
- in Python 2 and 3, // is integer division.

In order to achieve what you are looking for, there's different workarounds. For instances:

1. You can make sure to have at least one operand of your division in float. Eg:

   ```
   def median(lst):
       lst.sort()
       a=int(len(lst)/float(2))
       if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
           med=float((lst[a]+lst[a-1])/float(2))
       else:
           med=lst[a]
       return med
   print(median([4,5,5,4]))
   ```
2. You can use the import `from __future__ import division` (this needs to be done before any other imports). Eg:

   ```
   from __future__ import division

   def median(lst):
       lst.sort()
       a=int(len(lst)/2)
       if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
           med=float((lst[a]+lst[a-1])/2)
       else:
           med=lst[a]
       return med
   print(median([4,5,5,4]))
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I started programming just 4 days ago and the nuances are pretty obscure to me. Your answer really cleared things up!