# Why does f(50) differ radically from f(50.0)?

Tags: python, floating-point, int, precision, physics

I have defined a function in Python 2.7.15 which takes two inputs `(b,v)`, but I have noticed that `f(50,0.1)` produces very different results to those of `f(50.0,0.1)`. This is the function:

```
def f(b,v):
    h=b*v/math.sqrt(1-v**2)
    def dJ_dp(J,p):
        return [J[1],-J[0]+3.0/2*J[0]**2+1/(2*h**2)]
    J0 = [0.0000001,1/b]
    ps = np.linspace(0,15,50)
    Js = odeint(dJ_dp, J0, ps)
    us = Js[:,0]
    return (ps,1/us)
```

I've needed to define `dJ_dp` inside `f(b,v)` because it needs the value `h`. Why are the outputs so different? Why are they different at all?

My hypotheses was that something went wrong when defining `h` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Python 2.7 defines division differently for reals and integers. [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3)

Comment: the second entry of ```J0 = [0.0000001,1/b]``` is an integer division if b is an int, i.e. it's result will be 0 instead of 0.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably here: `J0 = [0.0000001,1/b]`.

If `b` is the int `50`, `1/b` will be done using integer division, and result in `0`. If `b` is the floating point `50.0` it will be done with floating point division and will result in `0.02`.

You could use `1.0` instead of `1` to force floating point arithmetic:

```
J0 = [0.0000001, 1.0/b]
# Here -----------^
```