# How to calculate two sequences depending on each other?

Tags: python, sequence

I'm trying to write sequences below, but it doesn't work. Could you please help me.

[image: sequences]

```
import math
def un(n_terms):
  def vn(n_terms):
    p = 0
    sum_un = 0
    while n_terms>=1:
      while p<=n_terms:
        sum_un = sum_un + (1//math.factorial(p))
        p = p + 1
    un(n_terms) = sum_un
    vn(n_terms) = un(n_terms) + (1//(n_terms * math.factorial(n_terms)))
  print(vn(10))
print(un(10))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the guide on how to ask questions. Please also try to provide examples of what you have tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: What is your error message ? I feel like it can come from the  `un(n_terms) = sum_un` line, it looks like you are trying do assign something to a function call

Comment: yes     un(n_terms) = sum_un
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: @Plopp im beginner, that's why i have a lil bit confuses, why can i use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your functions like this:

```
import math

def u(n):
    return sum(1/math.factorial(p) for p in range(n+1))

def v(n):
    return u(n) + 1/(n * math.factorial(n))
```

And then you can use them like this:

```
print(u(10)) # 2.7182818011463845
print(v(10)) # 2.7182818287037036
```

Comment: and in order to get float results i added (float) to denominators and it worked! is it proper way?

Comment: @thecarefulone That depends on the Python version you are using. With version >3 my code does work. Maybe you are still using version 2?

Comment: I did actually since im new it's written "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: im using 2.7.15, results of your code were integer (2), then i added (float), it showed float numbers as 2.718...

Comment: @thecarefulone ok then using `float` makes sense. Check this question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3

Comment: I got! Thank you very much for your help again, bless your heart