# Python nb_divide not available anymore in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I made a custom C-module to Python **2** a few years ago, which I now upgrade to Python **3**. The `PyNumberMethods` definition changed between 2 and 3, to register a class supporting certain operators.

**Python 2**

The class had two division operators. I used the first one and it worked.

```
typedef struct {
    binaryfunc nb_add;
    binaryfunc nb_subtract;
    binaryfunc nb_multiply;
    binaryfunc nb_divide; <-------
    binaryfunc nb_remainder;
    [...]
    binaryfunc nb_true_divide; <-------
    [...]
} PyNumberMethods;
```

**Python 3**

`nb_divide` got removed, and instead there is `nb_remainder`. Is this supposed to be the new function?

```
typedef struct {
    binaryfunc nb_add;
    binaryfunc nb_subtract;
    binaryfunc nb_multiply;
    binaryfunc nb_remainder; <-------
    [...]
    binaryfunc nb_true_divide; <-------
    [...]
} PyNumberMethods;
```

I tried `nb_true_divide` instead, and it also works. What is the difference between all these functions, and which one should I use if I want to support `foo.vector() / 100.0`

Answer (score 2):

There's also [`np_floor_divide`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyNumberMethods.nb_floor_divide) which, [as the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_FloorDivide) state:

> Return the floor of `o1` divided by `o2`, or `NULL` on failure. This is equivalent to the “classic” division of integers.

This is what was added. As for the differences, this has been asked already, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3) for example.

In a nutshell, if you want to attach behavior for your custom type based on `/` being used, define the `np_true_divide` slot. For `//`, use `np_floor_divide`.

Comment: Just wondering, so in my example I also need it for floats so `nb_true_divide` seems to be the better choice?

Comment: @DanielStephens Since `np_floor_divide` will allow you to attach behavior to the `//` symbol and `np_true_divide` to the `/` symbol I'd say that the `true_divide` slot is indeed what you're after.