# This code outputs different values for Python 3 and Python 2, how to get same result for both?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-conversion

```py
def mod_inverse_iterative(a, b):
    x, y, u, v = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while a != 0:
        q  = b / a
        r=b % a
        m = x - u * q
        n=y - v * q
        b, a, x, y, u, v = a, r, u, v, m, n
    return b, x, y

print(mod_inverse_iterative(66185,4080))
```

output python 2: (5, -275, 4461)
output python 3: (5, -1376.9583960493067, 11238.87370164165)

Comment: What have *you* done to try to solve the problem at hand?

Comment: most probably you have different division problem, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said in comments is due to python division. Check [this link](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#division) if you need more hints to port from python 2 to 3.

Also check this link from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#porting-to-python-3-0).

So, just change `q  = b / a` for `q  = b // a`