# Running a py file through subprocess gives different output than running the file directly

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use `subprocess` to generate a bunch of test cases, but something goes wrong.
Why is the following (simplified example) not working?

I have a first simple program `sphere.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
PI = 3.141592
radius = float(input( 'Give the radius of the sphere (in cm): ' ))

area = 4*PI*pow(radius, 2)
volume = 4/3*PI*pow(radius, 3)

print("\narea: {} cm²\nvolume: {} cm³".format(round(area,2),round(volume,2)))
```

Where an input of `4` results in (after running `python3 sphere.py`):

```
area: 201.06 cm²
volume: 268.08 cm³
```

Then I have another file, `generator.py` which runs the first one with `subprocess`:

```py
import subprocess

res = subprocess.run(["python", "sphere.py"], input="4",
                     capture_output=True, encoding="utf")

result_lines = res.stdout.split("\n")
for line in result_lines:
    print(line)
```

But this results in (different volume, after running `python3 generator.py`):

```
Give the radius of the sphere (in cm): 
area: 201.06 cm²
volume: 201.06 cm³
```

Strangely, when I changed the `volume` formula to `4.0/3.0*PI*pow(radius, 3)` it seemed to work fine...

What is going on here?

*using Python 3.8*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What usually happens on systems that have both Python 2 and 3 installed, is that `python` command is linked to Python 2, and `python3` is linked with... well obviously Python 3.

So while you are running your files from a shell with Python 3, ***the subprocess call invokes the Python 2 interpreter***. So the easy fix is to force it to use Python 3:

```
subprocess.run(["python3", "sphere.py"], ...)
```

Or use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to make sure the same Python interpreter is being used:

```
import sys

subprocess.run([sys.executable, "sphere.py"], ...)
```

Or, find a [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) to run a Python file from another one.

---

The hint for this problem is [the difference with the division operator between Python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21316968/6045800). In python 2, `4/3` will give 1. While in Python 3 it will give `1.333`. When you did `4.0/3.0` it forced the Python 2 interpreter to use float division as well so the problem was solved.

Interestingly, the use of `4` as the input made the two formulas equivalent (under Python 2). The `4/3` became 1 and didn't affect, and the extra power of `radius` became equivalent of multiplying by 4, hence the similar result.