# What do >> and << mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, operator-keyword

I notice that I can do things like `2 << 5` to get 64 and `1000 >> 2` to get 250.

Also I can use `>>` in `print`:

```
print >>obj, "Hello world"
```

What is happening here?

Comment: [FAQ: What do the operators `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `~`, and `^` do?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: Here, now you can plug those symbols into a search engine and have it actually search for them: http://symbolhound.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitwise Operation and Usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)

Comment: @user2357112 That'll be really helpful, thanks. And to those saying it's a basic question, it may be, but I had no concept of bitwise operators, so I would never have thought to look that up in documentation...

Comment: @joaquin it's now the number one result in google for python greater than greater than.

Comment: In the first case it is Bitwise Shift operators, in the second case it is overloaded for StringIO() objects. Take a look at this [print chevron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223647/double-greater-than-sign-in-python)

Answer (score 160):

The `>>` operator in your example is used for two different purposes. In C++ terms, this operator is overloaded. In the first example, it is used as a bitwise operator ([right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)),

```
2 << 5  # shift left by 5 bits
        # 0b10 -> 0b1000000
1000 >> 2  # shift right by 2 bits
           # 0b1111101000 -> 0b11111010
```

While in the second scenario it is used for output redirection. You use it with file objects, like this example:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    print >>f, 'Hello world'  # "Hello world" now saved in foo.txt
```

This second use of `>>` only worked on Python 2. On Python 3 it is possible to redirect the output of `print()` using the `file=` argument:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('Hello world', file=f)  # "Hello world" now saved in foo.txt
```

Comment: FYI that another common use of the right shift operator you might see in Python code will occur in Airflow files.

The Airflow framework overloads the '>>' operator to indicate one task is upstream from the other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389105/how-operator-defines-task-dependencies-in-airflow

Comment: you can actually override these operators via the `__rshift__` and `__lshift__` methods.

Comment: I'm getting that 2 >> 5 is equal to 0. I thought it should equal to 0.0001?

Comment: @teter123f the operation is binary. it is not decimal operation.

Answer (score 119):

These are bitwise shift operators.

Quoting from the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```
x << y
```

Returns `x` with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying `x` by `2**y`.

```
x >> y
```

Returns `x` with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the same as dividing `x` by `2**y`.

Comment: Perhaps an example would help, type a series of these in Python: `print bin(1)`, `print bin(1 << 1)`, `print bin(17)`, `print bin(17 >> 1)` and so on. You can see how it works without explanations.

Comment: Bit shift operator requires 2 operands so why operand is "print" and operand 2 an object? as in ```print >>obj, "Hello world"```

Comment: It is an answer to the context the OP provided (and thus known to OP) and not to the question asked.

Comment: @Qi Fan @z33k The question was edited to add the reference to print more than a year after this answer was written. The original question mentioned only `2 << 5` and `1000 >> 2`  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 65):

> 12 << 2
>
> 48

Actual binary value of 12 is "00 1100" when we execute the above statement Left shift ( 2 places shifted left) returns the value 48 its binary value is "11 0000".

> 48 >> 2
>
> 12

The binary value of 48 is "11 0000", after executing above statement Right shift ( 2 places shifted right) returns the value 12 its binary value is "00 1100".

Answer (score 39):

They are bit shift operator which exists in many mainstream programming languages, `<<` is the left shift and `>>` is the right shift, they can be demonstrated as the following table, assume an integer only take 1 byte in memory.

```
| operate | bit value | octal value |                       description                        |
| ------- | --------- | ----------- | -------------------------------------------------------- |
|         | 00000100  |           4 |                                                          |
| 4 << 2  | 00010000  |          16 | move all bits to left 2 bits, filled with 0 at the right |
| 16 >> 2 | 00000100  |           4 | move all bits to right 2 bits, filled with 0 at the left |
```

Comment: Exactly searching for this explanation.

Answer (score 15):

The other case involving `print >>obj, "Hello World"` is the "print chevron" syntax for the `print` **statement** in Python 2 (removed in Python 3, replaced by the `file` argument of the `print()` **function**). Instead of writing to standard output, the output is passed to the `obj.write()` method. A typical example would be file objects having a `write()` method. See the answer to a more recent question: [Double greater-than sign in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223647/double-greater-than-sign-in-python).

Answer (score 10):

These are the [shift operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

> x << y Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and
>   new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as
>   multiplying x by 2**y.
>
> x >> y Returns x with the bits shifted to the
>   right by y places. This is the same as //'ing x by 2**y.

Answer (score 8):

> Are "bitwise" operators.
> https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

```
>>> help("symbols")

+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Operator                                        | Description                           |
|=================================================|=======================================|
| "<<", ">>"                                      | Shifts                                |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "&"                                             | Bitwise AND                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "|"                                             | Bitwise OR                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "~x"                                            | bitwise NOT                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "^"                                             | Bitwise XOR                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

`x << y` 
Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying x by 2**y.

`x >> y` 
Returns x with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the same as //'ing x by 2**y.

> **PD:** In python 3.9 the operator **" | "** Applied to dictionaries merges dictionaries.

https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html

```
>>> x = {"key1": "value1 from x", "key2": "value2 from x"}
>>> y = {"key2": "value2 from y", "key3": "value3 from y"}
>>> x | y
{'key1': 'value1 from x', 'key2': 'value2 from y', 'key3': 'value3 from y'}
>>> y | x
{'key2': 'value2 from x', 'key3': 'value3 from y', 'key1': 'value1 from x'}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### 2 << 5 (shift to left)

Shifting 2 (in binary) 5 bits to the left. (inject zero to the right)

```py
bin(16) # '0b10'

shifted = bin(2) + '0' * 5 # '0b1000000'

int(shifted, 2) # 64
2 << 5 # 64
```

#### 1000 >> 2 (shift to right)

Shifting 1000 (in binary) 2 bits to the right. (inject zero to the left)

```py
bin(1000) # '0b1111101000'

# add 00 to the left and remove last digit from the right
# '0b 00(add these bits) 11111010 00(remove these bits)'
shifted = '0b0011111010'

int(shifted, 2) # 250
1000 >> 2 # 250
```

Answer (score 2):

I verified the following on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.8

I did print(100<<3)
Converting 100 to Binary gives 1100100.
What I did is I droped the first 3 bits and added 3 bits with the value '0' at the end.
So it should result as 0100000, and I converted this to Decimal and the answer was 32.

For my suprise when I executed print(100<<3) the answer was 800. I was puzzled.
I converted 800 to Binary to check whats going on.
And this is what I got 1100100000.

If you see how 800 was Python answer, they did not shift or drop the first 3 bits but they added value '0' to last 3 bits.

Where as print(100>>3) , worked perfect. I did manual calculation and cheked the print result from python. It worked correctly. Dropped last 3 bits and added value '0' to first 3 bits.

Looks like (100<<3) , left shift operator has a bug on Python.

Comment: No bug, it just isn't limited to 8 bits per number.

Comment: Both << and >> opertors should work with same logic. But << operator is behaving differently. I filed a behavioral bug with Python just jow.

Comment: @Nandish why... they do both work with the same logic

Answer (score 0):

```
<< Mean any given number will be multiply by 2the power
for exp:- 2<<2=2*2'1=4
          6<<2'4=6*2*2*2*2*2=64
```