# Double greater-than sign in Python

Tags: python

I was looking through some Python source code, when I came across this:

```
print >> sys.stderr, __doc__
```

What does the >> mean?  I've never seen syntax like this before.

Comment: @Shashank: Deprecated? I thought it was straight up annihilated. Deprecated implies it is still available but people are advised not to use it, which I don't think is the case here.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, sorry, what I mean to say is that it's deprecated in Python 2 and removed in Python 3. Usage of this syntax should not be encouraged, even if found in respected source code.

Comment: This thing is so difficult to search for, since too many examples use the python interactive shell and paste the triple greater-than sign everywhere...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the "print chevron" description in the [Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> `print` also has an extended form, defined by the second portion of the syntax described above. This form is sometimes referred to as “`print` chevron.” In this form, the first expression after the `>>` must evaluate to a “file-like” object, specifically an object that has a `write()` method as described above. With this extended form, the subsequent expressions are printed to this file object. If the first expression evaluates to `None`, then `sys.stdout` is used as the file for output.

The special syntax has disappeared in Python 3, as `print` was converted from a statement to a function.

Comment: Would you know what it does in a line like this? `m = (1 + 5) >> 1`

Comment: @MadPhysicist In that case it is a completely different thing: a [right bit-shift operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations).

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is specific to the `print` statement. Rather than the output going to standard output it sends the output to the file-like named after the `>>`, in this case standard error.

In an expression this is the right shift operator.