# How to execute a task after execution of all the tasks in airflow

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I have a Airflow DAG with around 10 tasks in it.

So now, I have another two tasks to execute only after execution of all these 10 tasks earlier.

Can you help me with this case.

Comment: If you are using Airflow 2.0.0 or greater, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367685/10569220) may help you. Specially if you want to set dependencies between two groups of tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify in your dag all the dependencies between your tasks with the right-bitshift operator.

Example for 3 tasks (make it up to your 10 tasks) :

```
[task1, task2, task3] >> final_task
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389105/how-operator-defines-task-dependencies-in-airflow) for more info.

Comment: If I add this piece of code , It would execute final_task three times. Like after execution of task1 , after execution of task2 and after execution of task3. But thats not my requirement. My requirement is , final_task should execute after complete of task1 , task2 and task3

Comment: Please check Airflow documentation [here](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/concepts.html#bitshift-composition).

Comment: @KoradaGanesh 
_If I add this piece of code , It would execute final_task three times. Like after execution of task1 , after execution of task2 and after execution of task3_
I thought the same thing because when I do this, final_task shows up 3 different times in the tree view.  However, if you look on the Graph tab, the DAG is in the desired format.  Each final_task in the tree view is actually the same task.  If you clear one, you clear them all and if you mark one as failed, they're all marked as failed.