# trying to understand LSH through the sample python code

Tags: python, similarity, locality-sensitive-hash

the concise python code i study for is [here](https://gist.github.com/greeness/94a3d425009be0f94751)

**Question A @ line 8**

i do not really understand the syntax meaning for "*res = res << 1*" for the purpose of "get_signature"

**Question B @ line 49** (SOLVED BY myself through another [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193927/what-does-these-operator-mean-python))

"*xor = r1^r2*" does not really make any sense to me, which the author later tried "*(d-nna(vor))*" to calculate "hash_sim" -- (refer to line 50)

**Question C @ about hash_sim in general**

that question is more to do with LSH understanding, what variable "*d*" (line 38) is doing in the sample code ---- which is later used to calculate *hash_sim* in line 50

**Question D @ line 20 and 24 -- synatx for "&"**

not only having problem in understand the syntax "*num = num & (num-1)*", but also unsure what function "nnz" is doing in the context of hash_similarlity. this question may relate to my question (-b-) when the author apply the "xor" into "*nnz*", and again equation for "*xor*" (question b) looks odd to me.

p.s.

both my python and LSH understanding are at the beginner level, and I kind of entering in the loop for this problem. thanks for taking your time to going through my confusion as well as the codes

Comment: Don't link to code. Copy/paste it here instead.

Comment: thanks, sorry but the original codes are a bit lengthy - as they try to do the cos and hash similarity all at once. I had a bit troubles in understand some of the syntax (which most likely means i have lack understanding for this topic)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. It's a left shift: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations It shifts the bits one to the left.

b. Note that `^` is not the "to the power of" but "bitwise XOR" in Python.

c. As the comment states: it defines "number of bits per signature" as `2**10` → `1024`

d. The lines calculate the bitwise AND of `num` and `num + 1`.
   The purpose of the function is documented in the comment above:
   "# get number of '1's in binary"

Comment: thanks, but follow up question (a) why they do shifts for the purpose of getting signiture. ALSO, it seems people use binary a lot (even taken as a grant), mm.. why is that, is that common for cos similarity? cheers