# Why does Python `**` use for exponentiation instead of the `^` operator?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, language-design, exponentiation

Why is `^` not squaring in Python? I know exponentiation is `**` instead, but what exactly is `^` and why wasn't that operator used instead?

For example `2^2=0`, `3^2=1`.

Comment: (Check out [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15194137/707111), specifically)

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. You want `**` for exponentiation.

Comment: The intention was to make the transition to Python easier for old Fortran programmers.

Comment: @BillBell Also C programmers.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: Another good reason.

Answer (score 8):

The `^` operator was already used for [bitwise xor](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

```
>>> x = 42; format(x, '08b')
'00101010'
>>> y = 137; format(y, '08b')
'10001001'
>>> z = x ^ y; format(z, '08b')
'10100011'
```

That leaves the old [Fortran-style](https://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/operate.html) `**` operator for exponentiation.

```
>>> base = 5
>>> exp = 2
>>> base ** exp
25
```

Answer (score 2):

The "^" symbol in python is a bit-wise exclusive OR (XOR) operator. An OR gate is true if one of the inputs OR another is true. The XOR gate is true if and only if just a single input is true. 00 and 11 are false. 01 and 10 are true. The bit-wise XOR can be used to check how many bits differ.

For example,

1. 2^2 = 10

   - ^10
     = 00
     = 0
2. 3^2 = 11

   - ^10
     = 01
     = 1