# I want x to be incremented

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=0
while x<20:
    x+=1
    y=x^x
    print(y)
```

So the expected output to be 2,27,256,3125………….
But all it keeps showing is 0 0 0 0.

Comment: `^` is not the correct operator. use `**`

Comment: ^ is the xor operator.  Anything xor-ed with itself is 0.  So you are repeatedly setting y to 0.

Comment: Note, that when corrected, the output would be 1, 4, 27, ... Rather than 2, 27, 256, ... (not sure where your expected output came from).

Comment: as mentioned use `**`, `for x in [ (x+1) ** (x+1) for x in range(0, 20)]: print(x)`

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2451386/2988730

Comment: Another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48938847/2988730

Comment: Also, your question should say something like "*I want print out `x`-squared using this loop*", not "*I want x to be incremented*". Please check out the [tour] and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you write well-written questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is bit-wise XOR.
Exponentiation is `**`

```
x=0
while x < 20:
    x += 1
    y = x ** x
    print(y)
```