# Why is this method saying the square of 1 is 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math.sqrt

I am writing a function that takes in two parameters: alpha and beta. It then calculates N, which is the square root of (alpha^2 + beta^2). And then it returns a list [x, y] where x = alpha / N and y = beta /N.  However, when I write out this code and run it, it calculates 1^2 incorrectly and says that it is 3 and not 1. This is resulting in an incorrect answer.  I have added print statements throughout my code to debug it but I can't find what is going wrong. Here is my code and the output.

```
def createQubit(alpha, beta):
"""
Parameters:
Probability amplitutde = alpha -> float
Probability amplitutde = beta  -> float

Return:
A qubit state -> list [x, y], which represents x|0> + y|1>
"""

# YOUR CODE
print(alpha, beta) #test
print(alpha^2, beta^2) #test

sum_of_sq = alpha^2 + beta^2
print(sum_of_sq) #test

N = math.sqrt(sum_of_sq)
if N > 0:
  x = alpha / N
  y = beta / N
  return [x, y]

pass

print(createQubit(1,1))

#OUTPUT: 
#1 1 --> alpha, beta
#3 3 --> alpha^2, beta^2
#0 --> sum_of_sq
#None --> result of function when you set alpha = beta = 1
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: `^` does not do what you think it does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193927/what-do-these-operators-mean

Comment: “python pow operator” would be a useful search.

Comment: Use `**` for squares. Like `alpha ** 2`.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Don't "tag" your title with languages; that's what real tags are for.